# Google Charts - How to stretch x axis over chart's full width

Tags: google-visualization

I can't figure out why Google Charts draws this simple chart aligned to center and doesn't fill entire white area.
Note: X axis is discrete because it represents weeks.

[image]

Do you have any idea what can I do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how the charts display when you use a discrete (`string`) axis.  If you want edge-to-edge lines, you need to use a continuous (`number`, `date`, `datetime`, `timeofday`) axis.  See an example of the differences here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/Xfx3h/.

Comment: hmm.., I'm afraid that's the only option.

Comment: If your weeks are numbered (like in your example), then you can input them as numbers and use the formatting options to change the way they are displayed, so they appear correct.